# Can the webdriver interact with the modal window that appears after calling the alert command?

Tags: webdriver-io

Can the webdriver io interact with the modal window that appears after calling the alert command? I need to press a button.

[image]

I tried using these commands:

```
browser.dismissAlert()
browser.acceptAlert()
```

But they didn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you Using asyc then do await before every browser command

```
await browser.dismissAlert()
await browser.acceptAlert()
```